# Owl carousel on meteor always set 5 items even on a smaller device

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, carousel

Well i'm using owl carousel and already is working but i have an issue i put the init on a rendered

```
Template.main.rendered = function (){    
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel();
});
```

and all the carousel code on a js document, it seems like works ok and well works ok on desktop but when  i test on a mobile device always set the numbers of items in the js document like

```
  $.fn.owlCarousel.options = {
        items : 5,
        itemsDesktop : [1199, 4],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979, 3],
        itemsTablet : [768, 2],
        itemsMobile : [479, 1],
}
```

so on page load no matter if is on a smaller device always load with five items then when resize the window the responsive stuff works but always load with five items you need resize the window to see them correctly, i hope you help me, thank you!

How looks on page load:
[image]

How looks on resize (and how should looks on page load)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the carrousel isn't rendender correctly

Try to put it on a [Meteor.setTimeout](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_settimeout)

Sometimes query plugins should be placed on a rendered but also on a timer

```
Template.main.rendered = function (){
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel();
  }, 0)    
});
```